# I use javascript to generate and download the txt file, but there is no response when I click the preview on the mobile device

Tags: javascript

> - Mobile device: iPhone 7 plus
> - Browser: Safari

How to make the download button have preview and download functions?

```
<script>
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
</script>
<button onclick="download('9591.txt','test')">download</button>
```

[image]

This problem has been resolved.
Solution：

```
const data= "test";
const blob = new Blob(data, {type: "text/plain"});
const fileName = "your.txt";
const element= document.createElement('a');
element.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
element.download = fileName;
element.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(element.href);
```

Comment: Not all browsers like automatic clicks on links. What happens if you create that link directly when the page loads (with a link text set), append it to the document, and then click that, instead of that button?

Comment: Try using a blob/object URL instead of a data URI.

Comment: `<a href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,test" download="9591.txt">click</a>`
Use <a> instead of <button> to get the same result.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, I changed to use blob link to solve the preview problem.

Comment: The problem of using download preview on mobile devices has been resolved